# MVC - Why session is lost after browser close?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, session-cookies

I'm using the code from that topic's accepted answer [ASP.NET MVC RememberMe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452656/asp-net-mvc-rememberme)

But, after log in I reopen the browser and I'm not logged in. Why ?

Comment: Does your browser delete history/cache on close? Or using some form of 'incognito' mode?

Comment: that was the purpose, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

To make this answer-able:

Make sure the browser you're using isn't setup to delete cache/cookies/session information on close (or at least add an exemption for local testing). also, make sure you're not browsing in privacy/incognito mode as that will delete information on close as well.

For a short-term work-around, you can keep the browser window (at least one tab) open and let visual studio open a new tab with each compilation. That should keep session information between tab views (until you inevitably close the window).