# "Remember me" functionality in a Login form

Tags: c#, checkbox, remember-me

I am using linq to entity connection. I want to keep user logged in once he entered into his account, This is my code. It's not working. Help, please

```
    if (this.ChkRememberme != null && this.ChkRememberme.Checked == true)
    {
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(TxtUserName.Text, TxtPassword.Text);
        cookie.Expires.AddYears(1);
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    }
```

Comment: I wouldn't put the password in the cookie use another token (just username would suffice) - have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452656/asp-net-mvc-rememberme

Comment: You may use another SO answers, like this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619791/implementing-remember-me-feature-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Can u help me with the exact code..?

Comment: Your choice to store the password in the cookie is very, very, very bad: http://www.troyhunt.com/2013/07/how-to-build-and-how-not-to-build.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 if (this.ChkRememberme != null && this.ChkRememberme.Checked == true)
 {
    int timeout = rememberMe ? 525600 : 30; // Timeout in minutes, 525600 = 365 days.
    var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(TxtUserName.Text, TxtPassword.Text);
    string encrypted = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
    var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encrypted);
    cookie.Expires = System.DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(timeout);// Not my line
    cookie.HttpOnly = true; // cookie not available in javascript.
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
}
```

Go to your web.config and find the authentication element. You can set the cookie expiration time (in minutes) there, like such:

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" 
               name="myCookie"                  <!-- optional, if you want to rename it -->
               timeout="2880" />                <!-- expires in 48 hours -->
    </authentication>
</system.web>
```

Source: [how to apply "Remember Me" in c#](http://forums.asp.net/post/5335853.aspx)

Hope this helps

Happy Coding..!!

Comment: do i need to write something in web config..??

Comment: FormsAuthenticationTicket and  rememberMe showing error on this part

Comment: I finally checked. And it didn't worked. Still I am gonna mark this completed, Because I dont code now. I run a development company. :P

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use [MembershipReboot](https://github.com/brockallen/BrockAllen.MembershipReboot) for authentication purposes in your app (samples are included).